# how to combine like and between?

Tags: mysql, query, phpmyadmin

i got tables like this:

| data_transaksi |
| --- |
| tgl_trans |
| ket |
| sim_wajib |

what i want to do is showing data from certain dates(tgl_trans) and ket values (values = SW,SS and penyesuian nilai tambah)

code that i used (for testing):

```
select tgl_trans, sim_wajib from data_transaksi 
where ket = 'SW' or ket = 'SS' or ket = 'penyesuaian simpanan tambah' 
and tgl_trans between '2021-01-01' and '2021-01-31'
```

expected output

| tgl_trans | ket |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | SW |
| 2021-01-02 | SP |
| --- | -- |
| 2021-01-30 | SW |
| 2021-01-30 | SP |

but output is:

| tgl_trans | ket |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | SW |
| 2021-01-01 | SP |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-02-01 | SW |
| 2021-02-01 | SP |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-03-01 | SW |
| 2021-03-01 | SP |
| --- | --- |

so its showing all the data where ket values = SW,SS and penyesuian nilai tambah

how to fix this?

any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You need parentheses around the OR conditions: `where (ket = 'SW' or ket = 'SS' or ket = 'penyesuaian simpanan tambah')
and tgl_trans between '2021-01-01' and '2021-01-31'` because AND has higher precedence than OR.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ just testing it out and its working! thanks!

Comment: You can self answer ;)

Comment: Also, learn this syntax:  `ket IN ( 'SW', 'SS', ... )`